# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.R

Tags: android, testing, junit, robolectric

I am trying to run a simple junit test with Robolectric 2.2 but I am getting the following using ADT package 22 error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/R
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.Setup.<clinit>(Setup.java:40)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createSetup(RobolectricTestRunner.java:137)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createSdkEnvironment(RobolectricTestRunner.java:115)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$3.create(RobolectricTestRunner.java:278)
    at org.robolectric.EnvHolder.getSdkEnvironment(EnvHolder.java:21)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getEnvironment(RobolectricTestRunner.java:276)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.access$100(RobolectricTestRunner.java:57)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.R
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 24 more
```

The code giving me the error follows:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import com.mycomp.myapp.R;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ListToWatchActivityTest {  

    @Test
    public void shouldHaveApplicationName() throws Exception {
        String appName = new ListToWatchActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        assertThat(appName, equalTo("MyApp"));
    }

}
```

Could someone help me understand why am I getting this error?

Thanks.

Comment: should you really create a new instance of an activity this way? 
Also, I think you don't really wish to compare between the app package name and "MyApp" as they are always different...

Comment: might be due to missing imports press ctrl+shft+o , after that clean and run your code

Comment: How are you running the junit? Maven? Ant?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Ok, now I use `Robolectric.buildActivity(ListToWatchActivity.class).create().get()` to get the desired activity instance. I thought I was just testing for the application name, what am I missing?

Comment: @KaranMer: No, I actually had to add the `android.jar` to the libs directory of an Android Application in eclipse.

Comment: @sheidaei: The built-in Ant in Eclipse. I have this project as Android Application Project.

Comment: @skip Then it might be the case that the built-in Ant plugin is not finding your android.R class. Try running it outside the eclipse. You can better investigate why it is failing.

Comment: @sheidaei: Adding `android.jar` in the `libs` folder got things working. I am not able to understand why a source folder `test` that is in build path ain't able to find `android.jar` which is also in the build path?

Comment: @skip I have encountered similar issues with different modules. They are supposed to look into the build path. I am not sure why this happens, it might be because of some overlapping specifications that overwrite the build path for a third party module in eclipse. This is my best guess. That's why I always test it natively if I encounter these kinds of issues. I am glad that you've found the issue and solved it.

Answer (score 5):

Add **android.jar** library to the classpath.

Comment: This worked for me. But I had to move the <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="TEST" name="android" level="project" /> entry in the .iml file below j-unit-4.11.